# Is there a way to load every label data and every SObject description data in Lightning Web Component using only Javascript without any Apex?

Tags: import, lightning-web-components

Is there a way to load every label data and every SObject description data using only Javascript without any Apex Server-side code?

How do I import * from @salesforce/schema or @salesforce/label?

I am looking for a way to get all labels or all SObject describe information details to retrieve in LWC at once.

I can see that such syntax is provided by ES6 and is used widely by Salesforce itself, however, it is not possible to use the following syntax in LWC:

```
 import * as schema from '@salesforce/schema' 
 import * as label from '@salesforce/label'
```

or this syntax

```
import {label, schema} from '@salesforce';
```

since both versions generate error

> LWC1512: Missing resource value for @salesforce"

or

> LWC1512: Missing resource value for @salesforce/label

Is there a way to load every label data and every SObject description data using only Javascript without any Apex Server-side code?

By the way, if we look as Salesforce Playground we could notice that 
[image]
the same syntax is used to import everything from `lwc`

```
import * as Engine from 'lwc';
```

however, if we try to insert such line into any of Lightning Web Component, we would receive the following error

> LWC1001: Invalid import. Namespace imports are not allowed on "lwc",
>   instead use named imports "import { LightningElement } from 'lwc'"
>   or
>   LWC1517: Invalid LWC import

Comment: +1 , SF does not support SELECT * In SOQL , I believe it would be same here to maintain consistency.

Comment: while `import * from` is used in Playground example, it is not possible to use the same line in the LWC component itself.

Comment: Maybe there is some different solution which wouldn't require `import * from`

Answer (score 4):

> An ES6 module is a JavaScript file that explicitly exports variables
>   or functions that other modules can use. Modules make it easier to
>   structure your code without polluting the global scope.

Everything in [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_javascript) which is imported and Exported is a ES6 [module](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_javascript_share_code).

> JavaScript files in Lightning web components are ES6 modules. By
>   default, everything declared in a module is local—it’s scoped to the
>   module.

As this is basically es6 and not just LWC, I tried searching `import all from es6`.

Surprisingly, there are many [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573779/es6-import-all-named-module-without-alias), I tried a solution from most accepted and most voted answer that suggested exporting * first and then importing it in [new component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard).

My code which exports all lables in `AllLables` module

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export * from '@salesforce/label';


export default class AllLables extends LightningElement {

}
```

when I try saving it, I get this error:

```
LWC1507: Exporting * from @salesforce/label is not allowed.
```

Apparently, even if there is the way in ES6, SF is intentionally blocking it, probably for the same reason it does not allow `SELECT * in SOQL`

You have to use Apex :(

Comment: +1 Perhaps even more so, a single object's metadata may well exceed 1MB of raw data, so for an org with hundreds of custom objects, such a component could easily consume a GB of RAM just for itself.

Comment: @sfdcfox you are right! One of the motivation to control the amount of code that needs to sent to the client. Another motivation is static analysis, the namespaced import (via `*`)  doesn't allow the LWC compiler to detect what piece of metadata the component relies on.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on top of [Pranay's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/252238/54851).

If you refer to the [Supported JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_javascript) documentation, there some JS functions which are *specific* to the LWC programming model. Those are not part of standard ES6 modules. And `@salesforce` is one of those.

> This developer guide explains how to develop Lightning web components and documents the [JavaScript functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference) that are unique to the programming model.

And because those are specifically developed by Salesforce as part of the model, Salesforce will always have full authority on the usage and syntax.

And one of the reasons I would think is to not allow an `import *` directive is the payload it may end up with (as sfdcfox has mentioned in the comments).