# How to use Custom Labels in design attribute on Lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, customlabel, design-attributes

I'm developing a LWC and i need to know how to use a custom label in design attributte on lighning web component.

Comment: Just to get more clarity on this. So you want to use a custom label in design attribute. You will pass this label api name in the app builder. I have tried it and it works with Lightning Component but not with the LWC. If you use it, it will be passed as the string instead of the value of the label.
I used to import for labels and checked using if else. Take a look on this twitter thread https://twitter.com/TheVishnuKumar/status/1107558419983032320

Comment: if I understand there is no way out for that, i need to internatinalize my component for the language of the user the value of the design attribute must be dynamic for the language of the user.

Comment: The other way is that you can use Aura Component on the parent. Use lwc component as a child component. get label value and pass it to the child lwc component.

Comment: thanks for your contribution but i will try it after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to load every label data and every SObject description data in Lightning Web Component using only Javascript without any Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252232/is-there-a-way-to-load-every-label-data-and-every-sobject-description-data-in-li)

Comment: @VishnuKumar if i use an aura component i can get the custom but i cant't use the it the file js-meta.xml because the bind is unidirectional in lwc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my search i have found this and i think it's the best answer at the moment: 
1) you can not use custom labels in configuration file, configuration file defines the metadata values for the component, including the design configuration for components.
2. you can use custom labels in your component check below post to understand.

https://disq.us/url?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.salesforcecodecrack.com%2F2019%2F01%2Fhow-to-access-custom-labels-in.html%3AsB2BN0wH5MkVtEHfEWGx71RdnKI&cuid=5683193